# Angular routing cant find Django template files

Tags: angularjs, django, django-templates, angularjs-routing

I'm developing an application using `Django` and `AngularJs routing`.

In my url configs for `Angular routing` I have this code:

```
app.config(function($routeProvider) {
$routeProvider
.when('/add', {
templateUrl : 'bultan/addReport.html',
controller : 'addReport'
})
```

In my Django template folder I got a folder called `bultan` which includes a template file named `addReport.html`

But seems like `AngularJs` cant find the template file address.

I tried `templateUrl : 'addReport.html',` and `templateUrl : 'templates/bultan/addReport.html',` ,But they didn't work either.

How can I make angular finds django template and shows it in its `ng-view` ?

Angularjs show error in browser console:

```
route.min.js:13:0
Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.26/$injector/modulerr?p0=bultanApp&p1=[$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.26/$injector/modulerr?p0=ngAnimate&p1=[$injector:nomod] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.26/$injector/nomod?p0=ngAnimate
C/<@http://localhost:8080/static/js/lib/angular.min.js:6:450
Zc/b.module</</b[e]<@http://localhost:8080/static/js/lib/angular.min.js:20:1
Zc/b.module</<@http://localhost:8080/static/js/lib/angular.min.js:20:1
e/<@http://localhost:8080/static/js/lib/angular.min.js:33:267
r@http://localhost:8080/static/js/lib/angular.min.js:7:288
e@http://localhost:8080/static/js/lib/angular.min.js:33:207
e/<@http://localhost:8080/static/js/lib/angular.min.js:33:284
r@http://localhost:8080/static/js/lib/angular.min.js:7:288
e@http://localhost:8080/static/js/lib/angular.min.js:33:207
gc@http://localhost:8080/static/js/lib/angular.min.js:36:309
fc/c@http://localhost:8080/static/js/lib/angular.min.js:18:170
fc@http://localhost:8080/static/js/lib/angular.min.js:18:387
Xc@http://localhost:8080/static/js/lib/angular.min.js:17:415
@http://localhost:8080/static/js/lib/angular.min.js:215:30
n.Callbacks/j@http://localhost:8080/static/js/lib/jquery-2.1.3.min.js:2:26906
n.Callbacks/k.fireWith@http://localhost:8080/static/js/lib/jquery-2.1.3.min.js:2:27724
.ready@http://localhost:8080/static/js/lib/jquery-2.1.3.min.js:2:29516
I@http://localhost:8080/static/js/lib/jquery-2.1.3.min.js:2:29707

C/<@http://localhost:8080/static/js/lib/angular.min.js:6:450
e/<@http://localhost:8080/static/js/lib/angular.min.js:34:97
r@http://localhost:8080/static/js/lib/angular.min.js:7:288
e@http://localhost:8080/static/js/lib/angular.min.js:33:207
e/<@http://localhost:8080/static/js/lib/angular.min.js:33:284
r@http://localhost:8080/static/js/lib/angular.min.js:7:288
e@http://localhost:8080/static/js/lib/angular.min.js:33:207
gc@http://localhost:8080/static/js/lib/angular.min.js:36:309
fc/c@http://localhost:8080/static/js/lib/angular.min.js:18:170
fc@http://localhost:8080/static/js/lib/angular.min.js:18:387
Xc@http://localhost:8080/static/js/lib/angular.min.js:17:415
@http://localhost:8080/static/js/lib/angular.min.js:215:30
n.Callbacks/j@http://localhost:8080/static/js/lib/jquery-2.1.3.min.js:2:26906
n.Callbacks/k.fireWith@http://localhost:8080/static/js/lib/jquery-2.1.3.min.js:2:27724
.ready@http://localhost:8080/static/js/lib/jquery-2.1.3.min.js:2:29516
I@http://localhost:8080/static/js/lib/jquery-2.1.3.min.js:2:29707
 angular.min.js:6:449
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't mix Angular and Django template files. From the point of view of Django, Angular templates are static files. On the other hand, Django template files are interpreted by Django, they are not served by the static server, so you can't request them via a URL.